# Exporting cypress memory and cpu uses to external API

Tags: memory, cypress, profiling, cpu

## Use Case

I am using cypress on multiple servers to run tests. While the cypress tests are running, i would like to record the CPU/Memory used by each instance of cypress.

Cypress provides a flag to log the cpu/memory uses on console -> https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#Log-memory-and-CPU-usage

```js
DEBUG=cypress:server:util:process_profiler cypress run
```

Is there any way to send this information to any external API, as I want to record the uses of CPU and Memory of each server?